# Maya – Why Print method can't be executed after Clear History command?

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

```
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)
print("hi")
```

The top line clear's the Maya Script Output window, and then the line below that is supposed to print `hi`. But when you run this, it flashes the `hi` output, and then clears everything. So the `cmds.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)` is executing last. Could someone explain this to me and help me understand how I can clean the Output Window AND THEN print `hi`.

I got the clear function from here:
[How can I clear the Maya Script Editor programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313339/how-can-i-clear-the-maya-script-editor-programatically)

Comment: You should try to debug your code – by doing so you will be able to see whats going on in your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also confirm that it clears the history and doesn't print, even if I make a loop and print 100 times.

There is a way around it using `evalDeferred` so that it doesn't execute right away:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)
cmds.evalDeferred("print 'Hello world!'")
```

Or if you want to run a lot of code after the clear command:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def run_code():
    # Run any code here
    print('Hello!')

cmds.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)
cmds.evalDeferred("run_code()")
```

Now the history clears and we see our print command as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## It seems that it's a bug.

I've tried three approaches and it turned out that all three don't work in case you execute these two lines simultaneously. ***But it definitely works if each line will be executed separately***: firstly `scriptEditorInfo()` method and secondly `print()` method.

Your approach:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)
print("Hello")
```

Second approach (pymel):

```
import pymel.core as pc

pc.scriptEditorInfo(clearHistory=True)
print("Hello")
```

Third approach (MEL):

```
scriptEditorInfo -clearHistory ;
print "Hello" ;
```

Comment: Is it not maybe related to the way Maya/Python stacks the execution of the code? Like the lifecycles of the code?...thanks for the examples by the way, but I marked @GreenCell's answer since he actually solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using:

```
import maya.cmds
reporter = mel.eval( 'string $tmp = $gCommandReporter;' )
cmds.cmdScrollFieldReporter(reporter, e=True, clear=True)
```

cmdScrollFieldReporter command needs defined reporter.